# ModuleNotFoundError for 'modin' even though it is installed by poetry

Tags: python-poetry, modin

On `import modin.pandas as modin_pd` line I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modin'`. I am using poetry & JupyterLab. If in the cell I type `!poetry add modin`, I get `ValueError` saying `Package modin is already present`.

So it cannot install `modin` because it is already installed but it cannot import it either. Any obvious solution that I am missing?

`pip freeze` command also shows `modin` to be installed. I also tried to install it via `pip install` but absolutely nothing let me to import this module in the end.

Comment: with `pip freeze --local` you can see only the packages in the local virtual env. Have you tried to remove the package with pip, or even better pip3, and then reinstall it?
Also be sure to have python >= 3.5 because it's in the modin requirements

Comment: @Y.Lucarelli In the end after restarting container with JupyterLab and reinstalling poetry viertual environment, I got where I started yesterday: to `KeyError: 'CPU'` on `num_cpus = ray.global_state.cluster_resources()["CPU"]` which is called by `import modin.pandas as modin_pd`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be this one [KeyError: CPU](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/213)

It can be solved by using `pip install psutil`

Comment: I have `psutil` installed. I looked in the logs and it seems `initialize_ray()` does not work correctly: it gives `ArrowIOError: Could not connect to socket /tmp/ray/session_2020-02-27_14-42-42_17463/sockets/plasma_store` error.

Comment: as this issues stands out [cannot connect to socket](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/468) it may be related to a limit of memory. It's not fixed yet, but the guy with this issue have found a way to avoid the error. Please check if his method also works for you